# How use Systems.henonheiles from InteractiveDynamics

Tags: julia, julia-pkg

I’m trying to duplicate the first example of trajectory evolution in the docs for the InteractiveDynamcis package (https://juliadynamics.github.io/InteractiveDynamics.jl/dev/trajectory/).

I’ve already created an environment into which I’ve added `InteractiveDynamics`, `DynamicalSystems`, `GLMakie`, and `OrdinaryDiffEq`.

In that environment, I executed:

```
using InteractiveDynamics
using DynamicalSystems, GLMakie
using OrdinaryDiffEq
```

But when I try to execute next…

```
ds = Systems.henonheiles()
```

… I get error:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: Systems not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
```

What is `Systems`?

I tried to add a package named `Systems` but no such package was found.

Answer (score 1):

Surely: `ds = DynamicalSystems.henonheiles()`

unless you do `Systems = DynamicalSystems` first

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what package versions you are using? On Julia 1.6.1 with the following package versions, the code above works:

```
  [61744808] DynamicalSystems v1.7.7
  [ec714cd0] InteractiveDynamics v0.15.1
  [e9467ef8] GLMakie v0.3.4
  [1dea7af3] OrdinaryDiffEq v5.57.0
```